# XPages - Partial refresh accordion control from extension library

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to do a partial refresh on my accordion control (from extension library). I have tried two approaches with no success.

Problem 1: I tried to put the accordion control inside a panel and tried to refresh the panel, however, this results in dojo error:

"Tried to register the widget with id==view:_id1:myaccordion but that id is already registered"

Problem 2: I tried to directly refresh the accordion by its id but then the accordion is broken. I can not destroy the accordion control as recommended on this link (http://www.mydominolab.com/2010/07/dijitdialog-inside-partial-refreshing.html) since it has many other issues and the link specifically deals with dialog control which is quite different from accordion.

Can you please suggest me something? Basically the accordion pane here displays the number of documents and I would like to do a timely refresh to update the count. Any help would really be appreciated.

Edit 1: Just adding a sample code for reference(This code would result in the problem 2 mentioned above and if surrounded by a panel and refreshed by panel id then problem 1 would arise):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:button value="Refresh" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="accordion1">
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:accordion id="accordion1">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:basicContainerNode label="Accordion 1">
                <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode label="Category x"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                </xe:this.children>
</xe:basicContainerNode>
            <xe:basicContainerNode label="Accordion 2">
                <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode label="Category y"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                </xe:this.children>
</xe:basicContainerNode>    

        </xe:this.treeNodes></xe:accordion>
</xp:view>
```

Edit 2: The above code does work when added a panel around it. It was my mistake to post it without testing that. However, I figured out that actual problem was Dojo layout which I am trying to use for the left navigation. Here is the sample code which breaks the accordion.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" 
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    pageTitle="S4EP TEAMGROUND"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:button value="Refresh" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="myPanel">
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
        <xp:div id="body" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
            style="height:100%;width:100%;align:center;">
            <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="persist" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="gutters" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:div id="left" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
                style="width:220px;height:50%">
                <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="region" value="left"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="splitter" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                    <xp:panel id="myPanel">
<xe:accordion id="accordion1">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:basicContainerNode label="Accordion 1">
                <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode label="Category x"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                </xe:this.children></xe:basicContainerNode>
            <xe:basicContainerNode label="Accordion 2">
                <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode label="Category y"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                </xe:this.children></xe:basicContainerNode> 

        </xe:this.treeNodes></xe:accordion>
</xp:panel>

            </xp:div>
        </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code plz. I dont use accordion very often but when i tried to refresh a Basic example it worked just fine.

Comment: Just updated my question. Please let me know if I am missing anything here..

Comment: I am still experimenting but i found an interesting fact. As soon s you add `dojoForm="true"`to your XPage where your use the accordion, it will break if you refresh it partial also in your working example.. so it has to do something with the classes loaded or how they get handled when this option is selected.

Comment: Ya, it is driving me crazy. Also, please do have a look at the link shared in the question. It was interesting how dialog control was handled. I am not able to get any clue for accordion though. Hopefully it gives you some hint and helps us to solve the problem here.

Comment: Wooho.. got a working example but i created the acordion with a script block programatical see "http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/layout/AccordionContainer.html": I am able to partial refresh it now, i will try to create a small example can't post the whole code here (to many lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is when you partial refresh your accordion widget dojo does not create you widget again. You can workaround that by programatical creating the widget inside a script block. so if you refresh the panel with your script block it willl get executed again and recreate your widget:

```
<xp:div id="body"   dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="height:100%;width:100%;align:center;">
        <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="persist" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="gutters" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:div id="left"   dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="width:220px;height:50%">
            <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="region" value="left"></xp:dojoAttribute>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="splitter" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:panel id="myPanel">
                <xp:panel id="leftAccordion">
                    <xp:scriptBlock type="text/javascript">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
                            dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
                            dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");

                            XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
                                var aContainer = new dijit.layout.AccordionContainer({
                                    style: "width:220px;height:50%"
                                },
                                "#{id:leftAccordion}");

                                aContainer.addChild(new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                                    title: "This is a content pane"
                                },'#{id:container1}'));

                                aContainer.addChild(new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                                    title: "This is as well"
                                },'#{id:container2}'));

                                aContainer.startup();
                            });]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:scriptBlock>
                    <xp:panel id="container1">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Entry "+ @Now().toLocaleTimeString();}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:panel>
                    <xp:panel id="container2">
                        <xp:text escape="true"  id="computedField2">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Entry "+ @Now().toLocaleTimeString();}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:panel>
                </xp:panel>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:div>
    </xp:div>
```

You can either use the container1 or container2 to add buttons to your accordion or create them also programatical see [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/layout/AccordionContainer.html). Here the Button with the partial refresh:

```
<xp:button
    value="Refresh"
    id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="myPanel">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

The only problem is that the accoridon gets closed again when you partial refresh the area but this solution worked for me in Firefox and IE10 =)

Comment: Interesting. Well, thank you. This atleast gets it working. But, I am not sure how the script block would work with my code. Since I have repeat control and many other dynamic variables. I know this can be accomplished in script library but it would get messier and less maintainable I think. Could you think of any other way around? I was thinking to build my own accordion instead using jquery since this wasn't working. :(

Comment: Move your repeat inside the Panel container1 or container2. You can also create new Container using a repeat control. You just have to pass the ids of the Container to the CS code to create the acordion. In jquery you would have to do the same =).

Comment: Ah, got it.  Just went through the code again. Looks convincing. Thanks a lot!..I guess this should do the trick.! Thanks again :)